# How do I pass JQuery text parameter as a variable

Tags: jquery, parameter-passing, jplayer

For the program JPlayer, I want to create an arbitrary amount of {..},{..} inside the jQuery statement's playlist parameter. The "newtest" variable will have the format {mp3: filename}, {mp3: filename2}... I can't seem to find the right syntax to create "newtest".

This code works:

```
var filename = "/mymusic/" + mydata[1];
// var newtest = new String('{ mp3: filename }');
script(type='text/javascript').
    //<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist({
                jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_N",
                cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_N"
            },
            [
                // newtest
                {
                    mp3: filename
                }
            ],....
```

This code doesn't create an error but won't access my music file:

```
var filename = "/mymusic/" + mydata[1];
var newtest = new String('{ mp3: filename }');
script(type='text/javascript').
    //<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist({
                jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_N",
                cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_N"
            },
            [
                newtest
                // {
                // mp3: filename
                //  }
            ],...
```

Both answers below work:

```
var newtest = { mp3: filename };

var myplayList = [
    { mp3: filename1 },
    { mp3: filename2 }
]
```

Thanks

Comment: Try `var newtest = { mp3:filename,....,...,...}` Don't end the last property with a "," comma. At the bottom just try `newtest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create the values *first*, in a more readable manner, and then pass the data in?

This way, you can pass the proper structure.

Your `parameter` is an object.
The `newtest` value of your parameter is actually a collection - an `array` of `objects`.

In the code below, it's simpler to see what's going on:

```
var params = {
    jPlayer: '#jquery_jplayer_N',
    cssSelectorAncestor: '#jp_container_N'
}

// This is an array of objects
var playList =[
    { mp3: 'filename1' },
    { mp3: 'filename2' },
    { mp3: 'filename3' }
]

var myPlaylist = newjPlayerPlaylist(params, playList);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Explanation

It looks like you are passing different data types in the two code blocks.
In your first code block, you're passing an array containing a single *object*:

```
[
  // newtest
  {
      mp3: filename
  }
]
```

In the second code block, `newtest` is a string, so you end up passing an array containing a *string*.

#### Solution

Set `newtest` as `var newtest = { mp3: filename };` and it should work.